# Use position_jitterdodge without mapping aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to produce a plot like the one obtained with the code below. However, I would like to dodge by "replicate", but without actually mapping an aesthetic (because I would like to assign fill and colors to other aesthetics).

```
dataset <- data_frame(sample = rep(c("Sample1","Sample2","Sample3", "Sample4"), each = 25),
                      replicate = sample(x = c("A", "B"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                      value = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 10))

ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = sample, y = value, fill = replicate)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.15, dodge.width = 0.75),
             show.legend = F)
```

I had hope using `group = replicate` instead of `fill = replicate` but this doesn't work. I can imagine a workaround using for example `alpha = replicate` as an aesthetic and setting `scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 1))` in case of duplicates, but I don't find this solution ideal and would like to keep all aesthetics available (other than x and y available for further use)

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = sample, y = value, alpha = replicate)) +
   geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.15, dodge.width = 0.75),
              show.legend = F) +
   scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 1))
```

The plot that I expect to get is:[image: expected result]

I hope my question makes sense, any hint ?
Best,
Yvan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `unite` the sample and replicate columns and use that as the x-axis, injecting a 'Placeholder' value for spacing between samples.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(20181101)
dataset <- data_frame(sample = rep(c("Sample1","Sample2","Sample3", "Sample4"), each = 25), 
                      replicate = sample(x = c("A", "B"), size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                      value = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 10))


dataset %>% 
  bind_rows({
    #create a dummy placeholder to allow for spacing between samples
    data.frame(sample = unique(dataset$sample),
               replicate = rep("Placeholder", length(unique(dataset$sample))),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }) %>% 
  #unite the sample & replicate columns, and use it as the new x-axis
  unite(sample_replicate, sample, replicate, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample_replicate, y = value, color = replicate)) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  #only have x-axis labels for each sample
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = paste0("Sample", 1:length(unique(dataset$sample)), "_B"),
                   labels = paste0("Sample ", 1:length(unique(dataset$sample)))) + 
  labs(x = "Sample") +
  #don't show the Placeholder value in the legend
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("A", "B"))
```

[image: sample_replicate]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jordo82, I would like to have less spacing between the replicates than between different samples.

Comment: @Yvan, edited to add a placeholder which spaces out things between samples